# autoincrement in access sql is not working

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

How can I create a table with autoincrement in access. Here is what I have been doing but not working.

```
CREATE TABLE People_User_Master(  
    Id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50), 
    Userid varchar(50) unique,
    Email varchar(50),
    Phone varchar(50),
    Pw varchar(50),
    fk_Group int,
    Address varchar(150)  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the constraint at the end

```
CREATE TABLE People_User_Master(   
Id AUTOINCREMENT 
  , Name varchar(50)   
, LastName varchar(50)   
, Userid varchar(50) unique   
, Email varchar(50)   
, Phone varchar(50)   
, Pw varchar(50)   
, fk_Group int   
, Address varchar(150)
, CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY(Id)
```

)

Updated to fit the actual answer (the definition of `INTEGER` on the `AUTOINCREMENT` column was not allowed). Leaving `PRIMARY KEY` at the same line as `Id AUTOINCREMENT` does work.

Comment: Ok, try removing the INTEGER after Id. (so the second line becomes Id AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: bingo ! it works ... please edit your answer so that I can accept it.

Id  AUTOINCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY also works
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove INTEGER (it conflicts with AUTOINCREMENT)

```
CREATE TABLE People_User_Master(  
Id AUTOINCREMENT primary key ,
Name varchar(50),
LastName varchar(50), 
Userid varchar(50) unique,
Email varchar(50),
Phone varchar(50),
Pw varchar(50),
fk_Group int,
Address varchar(150)
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using IDENTITY (supported by Jet4+)

```
CREATE TABLE People_User_Master
(
ID IDENTITY (1, 1), 
Name ..
```

Failing that;

```
ID AUTOINCREMENT,
```

Should work (note you don't specify a type)

Answer (score 1):

It may be working, but appears to fail if attempting an INSERT INTO with ID in the Column clause.  This seems to override MS Access AUTOINCREMENT.

This attempts to insert a record with ID=1 bypassing AUTOINCREMENT

```html
INSERT INTO People_User_Master 
       (Id, Name, LastName, Userid, Email, Phone, Pw, fk_Group, Address)
VALUES (1, "John", "Smith", "JS100", "JS@MyMail.Net", 12345678, "****","","")
```

Omitting ID lets AUTOINCREMENT function properly.

```html
INSERT INTO People_User_Master 
       (Name, LastName, Userid, Email, Phone, Pw, fk_Group, Address)
VALUES ("John", "Smith", "JS100", "JS@MyMail.Net", 12345678, "****","","")
```

Comment: How do I INSERT INTO while omitting values and having MS Access SQL select an autoincrement value or a 'Next Value For' SQL Server like syntax for the ID sequence value for a destination MS Access Table?